# Dual Boot Ubuntu - Windows 10 | Can't switch back to windows

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, acer, bios, grub-legacy

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 in dual-boot with windows 10. 
So far so good, but when I wanted to return to the windows I saw that I didn't have that option.

**Critical Notes:**

- I **can't** access BIOS, due to Acer fault, through the key shortcuts F2, F12 or any other.
- Actual Boot Order does not allow run from usb or cd primarily.
- Ubuntu is the default OS and is installed in **Legacy**.

**Already Tried Without Results:**

- Boot-Repair and OS-Unistaller.
- Run from Windows and Ubuntu bootable usb.
- Run from Knoppix CD.
- Followed a few tutorials to change Legacy to UEFI.

**Ideas:**

- Enter the BIOS through an alternative process.
- Update BIOS from Linux.
- Uninstall Linux from Linux.
- Change Legacy to UEFI.

Any Help?

Comment: But you didn't try `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: I tried, it didn't recognize Windows Partition. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Regarding what you said *I can't access BIOS, due to Acer's fault, through the key shortcuts F2, F12 or any other.* - It used to be that you could access the BIOS by pressing the appropriate key immediately after the splash screen appears when the computer is booting. The latest model computers with UEFI boot so fast that  in order to access the BIOS sometimes you have to press the same key **before** you see the splash screen when the computer is booting.

Answer (score 2):

> Ubuntu is the default OS and is installed in **Legacy.**

That's the problem. With Windows (almost certainly) installed in EFI/UEFI mode and Ubuntu installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, there's no way for the BIOS-mode GRUB to start the EFI-mode Windows. If you followed instructions to activate BIOS/CSM/legacy support, those instructions were *wrong.* (There *are* cases when this is appropriate, but obviously not in your case.)

> Change Legacy to UEFI.

That's half of the solution. You'll also need to install an EFI-mode boot loader for Linux. I'll get to that shortly. In the meantime, you *must* find a way to access either your firmware setup utility or your computer's built-in boot manager. I realize you say you can't access your "BIOS" (you mean the firmware setup utility; you don't have a BIOS), but you should focus on overcoming that problem. Some computers are very sensitive about the timing of keys to get into the firmware setup utility or boot manager, so you should try Esc, Del, Enter, and every function key multiple times. You might also contact Acer's technical support or post on an Acer-specific forum for help on this score. As a last-ditch effort, you can unplug your hard disk from the computer and it will probably boot into the setup utility.

If you can get into the firmware setup utility:

- Disable the CSM/legacy support.
- Disable any "fast start" option or anything with a similar name. This feature can be one reason why keypresses won't get you into the setup utility or boot manager, so disabling it can help.
- Look for other options that might affect your ability to boot into the setup utility. For instance, if one is present, you might want to activate an option to do a full USB initialization, which may get the keyboard working during boot.

The built-in boot manager lets you select between OSes, and may also have an option to start the setup utility. It should let you select between Windows and a BIOS-mode boot option that will launch GRUB and Ubuntu. You can use this to get into Windows. If you plug in an EFI-bootable USB flash drive, you should be able to boot it from this menu, too. This brings us to the next point....

Once you're able to control your boot process, you must install an EFI-mode Linux boot loader. There are a number of ways you can do this:

- Boot the Ubuntu installer *in EFI mode* and re-install Ubuntu. Since you've not used it for long, this may be an acceptable solution. You can verify an EFI-mode boot by looking for the `/sys/firmware/efi` directory. If it's present, you've booted in EFI mode; if it's absent, you've booted in BIOS mode.
- Boot the Ubuntu installer *in EFI mode* and run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. This will normally set up an EFI-mode version of GRUB.
- Disable Secure Boot, download a USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a boot medium with it. You should then be able to boot rEFInd, which should enable you to boot either Windows or Ubuntu. If that works, boot to Ubuntu and install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package. This will give you rEFInd, rather than GRUB, as your primary boot tool. You may be able to re-enable Secure Boot at this point, but that's optional.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your great answer.

_In the meantime, you must find a way to access either your firmware setup utility or your computer's built-in boot manager._

Here is the main problem. I'm already trying to contact acer in search of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Win10 bootloader, but here was my solution for getting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu dual-booting from GRUB.

1. Disconnect every drive except the Windows one.
2. Install Windows on the drive.
3. Disconnect your Windows drive and attach your other drive, make sure it is attached to the lowest-numbered SATA port on your motherboard (mine is SATA_0).
4. Install Ubuntu to that drive.
5. Reconnect your drives, make sure the Ubuntu drive is first in your boot order.
6. Install boot-repair and run it.
7. You should be up and running.